# Avoid files from being overwritten during git merge

Tags: git

Consider the following scenario. I have three branches - `Master`, `Develop` and `Test`.  All three branches have a config file (say a `JenkinsFile`) that contains branch specific configuration. Please note that the configuration in this file is different for all three branches. Now, I create a feature branch off `Master`, make some changes and merge this feature branch with `Develop` and then with `Test`.

The question is - how do I prevent the `JenkinsFile` from being overwritten by any merge? I want the `JenkinsFile` to remain intact and not be affected by any merge. Is there a way to "lock" these files? Does `gitignore` work in this case?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is - how do I prevent the JenkinsFile from being overwritten by any merge? I want the JenkinsFile to remain intact and not be affected by any merge. Is there a way to "lock" these files?

No.

There is a completely different way to go about this, though, that sidesteps the entire problem.  In fact, there are multiple ways, but I'll show just one.  There's an unfortunate problem in terms of getting *to* the state where things all work as desired, but once you do get there, you're good.  The end goal here is to *not* have a committed file named `Jenkinsfile` (or `JenkinsFile`, but I've used the lowercase-F spelling below) whose content is branch-dependent.  Instead, just have an *uncommitted* work-tree-only file whose name is `Jenkins[Ff]ile` and whose content is branch-dependent.  Make the *committed* files have other names.

#### Background

Fundamentally, `git merge` works by *combining work done*, i.e., combining the changes to some file(s) since some common starting point.  But Git doesn't *store* changes; Git stores *snapshots*.  This creates a problem for `git merge`, and the solution requires that you understand how Git's *commit graph* works.

Almost every commit in a Git repository has at least one *parent* commit, which is that commit's immediate predecessor.  Most have *exactly* one parent; commits of type "merge" have at least two, and usually exactly two.  In fact, the presence of more than one parent is what defines a commit to be a merge commit.  The other common special case is that the very first commit in a repository has *no* parent, because it can't have one, because it was the first commit.  (Commits with three or more parents are called *octopus merges* but they do nothing you can't do with regular merges, so they're mainly for showing off. :-) )

These links, in which a commit stores the hash ID of its parent(s)—remember that each commit is found by its unique hash ID, that Git assigned to the commit when you made the commit—form backwards chains.  These backwards chains *are* the history in the repository.  History is commits; commits are history.  A branch name simply identifies the (single) *last* commit that we wish to claim to be part of that branch:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

Here, instead of actual hash IDs, I've drawn in single uppercase letters that stand in for each commit.  The name `master` holds the actual hash ID of commit `H`.  We say that `master` *points to* `H`.  `H` holds the hash ID of its parent `G`, so `H` points to `G`, which points to `F`, and so on, backwards down the line.

Nothing inside any commit can ever change, so we don't need the internal arrows, we just have to remember that they go backwards.  It's actually very hard to go forwards, in Git: almost all operations start at the end(s) and work backwards.  Once we have more than one branch, this gives is a picture that looks like this:

```
          G--H   <-- master
         /
...--E--F
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
              \
               K   <-- test
```

To `git checkout` a branch means *extract the snapshot from the tip commit of that branch`.  So`git checkout master`extracts the snapshot from commit`H`, while`git checkout develop`or`git checkout test`extracts those snapshots in turn.  Also, doing a`git checkout`of some branch name attaches the special name`HEAD` to that branch.  This is how Git knows *which* branch—and commit—is the *current* one.

When you run `git merge`, you give Git the name of some other commit.  That doesn't have to be a branch name—any name for a commit will serve—but giving it a branch name works fine, since that names the tip commit of that branch.  So if you `git checkout master` and then run `git merge develop`, you start with:

```
          G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--E--F
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
              \
               K   <-- test
```

and Git finds commit `J`.  Git then works backwards from both the current commit `H` and the named commit `J` to find the *merge base* of these two commits.

The merge base is, loosely, the first commit we get to from both tips.  That's a commit that's on *both* branches, and in this case, that's obviously commit `F`.  **The idea of a merge base is crucial to understanding how merge works.**  Since the goal of the merge is to *combine work*, and that work can be found by comparing the snapshot in commit `F`, one comparison at a time, to each of the two tip commits `H` and `J`:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-F> <hash-of-H>    # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-F> <hash-of-J>    # what they changed
```

To combine the changes, Git starts with all the files from `F`, and looks at which files we changed and which ones they changed.  If we both changed *different* files, Git takes ours or theirs as appropriate.  If we both changed *the same* file—[this eventually brings up a philosophical problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) which we'll get back to in a moment—Git attempts to smash our changes together with their changes, by assuming that if we touched some source line and they didn't, it should take ours, and if they touched some source line and we didn't, it should take theirs too.  If we both touched the *same* lines of the *same* file, then either we did the exact same thing *to* those lines—in which case, Git takes *one copy* of that change—or there's a conflict.

If there are no conflicts, Git applies these combined changes to the snapshot in the merge base—in `F`, here—and uses the resulting files to write out a new snapshot.  That new snapshot is a commit of type *merge commit*, having two parents.  The first parent is the commit we were on before, `H`, and the second is the one we named with our argument, `J`, so the merge looks like this:

```
          G--H
         /    \
...--E--F      L   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          I--J   <-- develop
              \
               K   <-- test
```

Note that nothing happens to any existing commit, nor to any other branch name.  Only our own branch name, `master` (to which `HEAD` is attached), moves; `master` now points to the new merge commit that Git just made.

If the merge goes badly, due to merge conflicts, Git will leave a mess behind.  The *index*, which I'm not going to get into here, will contain all the conflicting input files, and the work-tree will contain Git's attempt at merge, along with conflict markers.  Your job is to clean up the mess, fix up the index, and finish the merge (with `git merge --continue` or `git commit`—the `--continue` just runs `commit`) by hand.

#### Your problem: `Jenkinsfile`

Suppose that in commit `F`, the merge base, there is a file named `Jenkinsfile`.  This same file, with this same name, appears in commits `H` and `J`.  The copies in `H` and `J` differ—you said they do, so we'll assume that they do.  Therefore *at least one* differs from `F`, and perhaps both differ from `F`.

Git is going to assume that the file that is named `Jenkinsfile` in both branch tips is the *same* file that is named `Jenkinsfile` in `F`.  Obviously, it's not quite the same file—the contents differ—but Git will *assume* that it is, and that you're trying to combine work done on it.

So, Git will diff the version of `Jenkinsfile` in `F` against that in `H`, and then diff it again, against the version in `J`.  There will be *some* changes.  If both branch tips have changes, Git will combine them (or declare a conflict).  Result: *bad*.  Otherwise, Git will take the version of the file from whichever "side" changed it.  Is that the side you want?  If so, result: *good*.  If not, result: *bad*.

**In summary**, for this scenario, there are three possible results:

- Base vs HEAD is the only change: the result is fine.
- Base vs theirs is the only change: result is bad.
- Base vs HEAD and base vs theirs both have changes: result is probably bad.

It is of course possible that merge base commit `F` has *no* file named `Jenkinsfile`.  And, it's possible that one or both *commit* has no such file.  In this case, it gets a little trickier.  We'll get to that in a moment.

#### The solution (and some issues getting there)

The solution here is to avoid having a single, fixed-name file, such as `Jenkinsfile`, in all commits when that file is intended to be branch-dependent.  Suppose, instead, that commit `F` contains `Jenkinsfile.master` and `Jenkinsfile.develop` and `Jenkinsfile.test`.  Then commit `H` will have a `Jenkinsfile.master` and `Jenkinsfile.develop` and `Jenkinsfile.test` too, and the *changes* from `F` to `H` in `Jenkinsfile.master` will be the ones you want to keep.  Since commit `J` is in branch `develop`, it should always either have the *same* changes—imported from `master` at some point—or *no changes at all*.  Git's merge will therefore do the right thing, in both cases.

The same logic applies to each of the other such files.  Note that at this point, the commits identified by all branch tips should have *no* file named `Jenkinsfile` (without a suffix) at all.  This is, of course, an idealized goal-state: to get there, you must actually make new commits in each branch, renaming the existing `Jenkinsfile`.  But this will have *no effect at all* on any *existing* commits.  All of that history in your repository is frozen for all time.  This means that at some point, you'll run `git merge` and `git merge` will locate a merge base commit that has only `Jenkinsfile`, not `Jenkinsfile.master`, and not `Jenkinsfile.develop` or any other suffix.

Let's assume now that in `H` and `J`, you have already done this renaming, but in merge base `F`, you have not—obviously, since it's a historic commit.  So `F` has a `Jenkinsfile` and no renamed files, while `H` and `J` have *no* `Jenkinsfile` but do have the renamed files.

Now, remember above where we showed the `git diff`s that `git merge` runs, to figure out what has changed since the merge base.  One of the arguments is `--find-renames`.  This directs Git to *guess* whether the file `Jenkinsfile` in `F` is "the same" file as `Jenkinsfile.master` in `H`, when comparing `F` and `H`.  The same goes for the comparison of `F` vs `J`: is the old `Jenkinsfile` the same file as the new `Jenkinsfile.develop`?

If you followed the link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus you will see that there's no philosophical right answer to the question of identity-over-time.  But Git has *its* right answer, which is: *If the file has a similarity index of 50% or better, it's the same file.*  We don't need to worry here about how Git computes this similarity index (it's a bit complicated); chances are very good that Git will detect the rename in both cases.

**What this means in practice** is that the *first* time you run this `git merge`, Git will immediately declare a merge conflict, of the type I like to call a *high level* conflict.  That is, Git will say that `Jenkinsfile` was renamed in *both* branches, but to two different names.  Git doesn't know whether to use the master version, or the develop version, or both, or neither, or what.  It will just stop with a merge conflict.  **This is OK** because it gives you a chance to resolve the conflict, which you should do by selecting the `Jenkinsfile.master` file as it appears in the `master` or `--ours` branch, *and* selecting the `Jenkinsfile.develop` file as it appears in the `develop` or `--theirs` branch, as your merged results.  Put these two files into the index while removing the original name:

```
git rm --cached Jenkinsfile
git checkout --ours Jenkinsfile.master
git checkout --theirs Jenkinsfile.develop
git add Jenkinsfile.master Jenkinsfile.develop
```

You have now resolved the conflict by choosing to keep both files as they appear in both branch tips.  You can now commit the result.

Every time you do a merge that uses one of the historic, single-`Jenkinsfile` commits, you'll need to check that the merge result is correct, or resolve any conflicts.  (If it's not correct, immediately after merging, you can fix it in place and use `git commit --amend` to push the original merge aside and choose a new result as the merge commit.  If you don't notice a bad merge, it's a bit more painful, but the recovery is similar in the end anyway.  Remember how Git does merges, and work through the two `git diff`s, to see how putting the right result in *any* tip commit gets you where you need to go.)

#### Last, now there's no `Jenkinsfile`

Now that there's no file named `Jenkinsfile`, you'll have to redirect any software that wants to use such a file.  There are multiple solutions (depending on the software and your OS), including making a symbolic link from `Jenkinsfile` to the correct per-branch checkout.  (Make sure the symbolic link does not get committed, or you'll be right back to the same merge issue when Git tries to merge two potential symlink target changes.)

Comment: Even it was possible, storing multiple versions of the configuration file in different branches is the wrong thing to do. For example, how would you update it if add a new setting? Visit all branches?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping a file different between branches is super hard, especially one that changes from time to time.

A better solution is to have settings.environment.json files that contain settings for different environments and make your software use different settings file depending where it runs.

Having said that it's best not to keep your production settings in git. The deployment pipeline should contain passwords etc, not your version control system. In this scenario the settings file in all branches contains DEV settings (which are OK to be public) and the pipeline overwrites the settings with TEST and PROD values when it prepares the package for deployment to the target environment.